# TopNavigation Bar is shown Null for Report Centre site in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: c#

I have create a Publishing site collection and when i try to get the TopNavigation Bar for 'Report Centre' site I get it null. Why ? However for Document Centre,News etc it is not null. Can someone explain me ?

```
string siteUrl = "http://sp07:9988/sites/testpubsite/Reports";
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
        {
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
            var topBar = web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar;
        }
```